# Compiling for amd64 under i386 Debian

Tags: linux, gcc, 64-bit, debian

Cheers,

I want to avoid problems with compiling my code on `amd64`, yet **I don't have a 64-bit CPU** available and have no hopes of getting upgrade to my machine any time soon. I have no dreams of testing the code (although that should theoretically be possible using `qemu-system`) but I'd like to at least compile the code using `gcc -m64`.

Basic idea works:

```
CFLAGS=-m64 CXXFLAGS=-m64 ./configure --host x86_64-debian-linux
```

However, the code depends on some libraries which I typically install from Debian packages, such as `libsdl1.2-dev`, `libgmp3-dev` and such. Obviously, getting 64-bit versions of packages installed alongside of 32-bit versions is not a one-liner.

What would be your practices for installing the 64-bit packages? Where would you put them, how would you get them there and how would you use them?

To repeat, I **don't have** 64-bit CPU and cannot afford getting a new machine.

I have already set up `amd64-libs-dev` to give some basic push to gcc's `-m64`.

Attempted so far:

- Setting up a 64-bit chroot jail with `debootstrap` in order to simplify installation of 64-bit development packages for libraries. Failed since finishing the setup (and installing anything afterwards!) requires 64-bit CPU.
- Installing `gcc-multilib` and `g++-multilib`. This appears to do nothing beside depending on `libc6-dev-amd64` which I already installed through `amd64-libs-dev`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using debian, before you can use `gcc -m64`, you need to install `gcc-multilib` and `g++-multilib`. This will also install all files needed to link and create a 64bit binary.

You don't have to have a 64bit capable CPU for this either.

Then you can call GCC as follows:

```
$ gcc -m64 source.c -o source
```

As for external libraries, debian takes care of that if you have multilib installed. I have a 32bit machine that compiles 64bit code for another machine and links a handful of libraries (libpng, libz for example). Works great and the executable run (debian to debian).

Comment: This looks precisely like the thing I need! Can you specify in greater detail how to install the libraries in parallel with the 32bit ones? I'm currently pained by libgmp3-dev, which on i386 does not include the 64-bit header (they have differing headers per arch).

Comment: I'm not sure about libgmp3-dev, but most (all?) of the dev packages install both 32bit and 64bit if multilib support is present (i.e gcc-multilib/g++-multilib is installed). Try reinstalling (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgmp3-dev`) and see if you can compile.

Comment: Unfortunately, reinstalling libgmp3-dev, as expected, still didn't install /usr/include/gmp-x86_64.h (as far as I know, contents of a package do not depend on the other packages installed). I'll try filing a wishlist bug report so that they include 64-bit header. Also, as far as I can tell, only one version of lib*.a is installed in most -dev packages, perhaps 32-bit libs can be linked with 64-bit code?

Comment: Did further testing. Mesa OpenGL libraries have valid headers, but don't link properly (well, was sorta expected, wasn't it?) so even the configure phase does not pass.

Comment: The -dev packages still conflict between platforms, so it unfortunately does not seem to be so simple.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the `dchroot` package to set up a simple `chroot(8)` environment -- that way you can compile real amd64 binaries in a real 64-bit setting with proper libraries and dependencies.  This surely works the other way (i.e. I am using i386 chroots on amd64 hosts) but I don't see why it shouldn't work the other way if your cpu supports amd64.

*Edit:* Now that you stress that you do not have a amd64-capable cpu, it gets a little trickier.  "In theory" you could just rebuild `gcc` from source as a cross-compiler.  In practice, that may be too much work.  Maybe you can just get another headless box for a few dollars and install amd64 on that?

Comment: His CPU does **not** support 64bit.

Comment: Which is why I amended my answer.

Comment: I simply don't have the resources available to get any kind of new machine. I'm in desperate need of any desktop as-is (I daily work on a 3yr old cheap laptop on verge of breakdown) yet I can't afford it. Still, I want my software to at least compile on 64-bit.

Comment: That's a completely different story story.  Writing portable code is not dependent per so on access to another machine (though that helps with testing).

Comment: I only need this to devise a proper method to allow compiling on both 32- and 64-bit compilers, and to occasionally test if I broke it -- I don't dream about doing further testing than that :-)

Answer (score 0):

check out [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Installing_apps_in_a_32-bit_chroot_in_AMD64_Debian_system) fine article that describes how to easily create a 32bit chroot, where you can install all the 32bit tools (gcc and libs)

Comment: The original poster has the opposite problem: he already has i386, he needs amd64. With that in mind, the article should be applicable.

Comment: @Dirk A 64-bit chroot isn't going to work if he doesn't have a 64-bit processor

Comment: @PiedPiper, I need chroot only for libraries, not for running executables. gcc -m64 works, and Debian already includes basic 64-bit development libraries in i386 distro.

Comment: Your and Dirk's answers were the most promising, despite my CPU not supporting AMD64 (as was stated in the question). I spent last hour-and-a-half setting up an amd64 chroot, however I was unable to get apt-get to install stuff into the chroot.

Comment: QEMU user mode can be used for this though.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Debian distinguish between `lib32` and `lib64` directories? In that case, you can just grab the packages and force them to install, regardless of architecture.

If that does not work (or would hose your system!) I would set up a chroot environment and apt-get the 64-bit libraries into there.

Comment: No -- multi-arch support is a current release goal we are working on and not yet supported.

Comment: While this is quite interesting proposal (I did not know about /usr/lib64) it still wouldn't work -- files in /usr/share/doc and the package names, which are the same between archs, would still collide.

Answer (score 0):

Check out pbuilder, It can create build environments for many architectures, some [instructions here](http://www.tolaris.com/2009/03/31/backporting-debian-packages-with-pbuilder/)

Comment: While very promising, this also failed. 
...
P: Extracting libslang2 \n
P: Extracting util-linux \n
E: Execution failed: Exec format error \n
E: Internal error: install \n
E: cdebootstrap failed \n
W: Aborting with an error \n
I: cleaning the build env  \n
I: removing directory /var/cache/pbuilder/build//16153 and its subdirectories \n

Answer (score 0):

Try cross compiling SDL, gmp and other libraries yourself. Or manually extract the files you need from the Debain packages.